# way to get the detail of any antivirus

Tags: c, windows

I got this requirement for one the desktop application,in which we need to check whether an Anti virus installed and if yes need to get the details like name and whether it’s updated or not. and name of exe to update and scan the system drive through command prompt

if there is any c/c++ code for windows then please tell me as soon as possible

i have implemented through WMI classes. its working fine with the AVG anti virus becauese AVG have its both exe(Scan and update) in the same folder path .but this is not true in case of Mcafee. so i have to hard code some path but i d"not want to hardcode path ,

so, please tell me  if there is any other way to get the detail of any antivirus.

Comment: This question is actually better formed than the first one...